# vue js to detect external links

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am rendering some html content from the service. Some of those html content having links to external web pages. There I need to stop redirecting to those pages and redirect to some other routes which are defined in the frontend. My attempt is as below.

```
 <div v-html="content" class="content" @click="handleClicks">
 </div>

  handleClicks(event) {
    
       let { target } = event;
       const url = new URL(target.href);
       if(url=="http://abc.apps/recharge") {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.$router.push('/myaccount/detailed');

       }
 },
```

But it will not redirect to my defined route. It's directly moving to http://abc.apps/recharge. Where I was get wrong here?

Comment: can you show some more code, navigation depends on the nature of HTML elements used in content, eg. if it <a> tag and you are binding click event later and from where try to stop the navigation ?

Comment: a tags are used

Comment: then probably you can override natural functionality of <a> tag either with JS or CSS property like pointer events. But you need a right locator to access these tag.

Comment: can you give an example pls

Comment: I think it is because of your if condition `if(url==..)`. You are only asking for one URL. If the URL has `https` but you don't check it, the page will open of course.